# Alternative of \resizebox{\textwidth}{!} for homogenously fixing font size for multiple lines

Tags: fonts, graphics, line-breaking, fontsize, microtype

I am trying to list three different sentences:

```
 \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.4in}p{0.3in}p{4in}}
     Fall &2015 &Teaching Assistant, Machine Learning (Andrew Ng)\\
     Winter &2016 &Teaching Assistant, Cryptography (Dan Boneh)\\
     Winter &2017&Teaching Assistant, 
     Probabilistic Graphical Model (Stefano Ermon)\\
\end{tabular}
```

But this gives

[image]

So I changed it and used `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}` from `graphicx` package.

```
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.4in}p{0.3in}p{4in}}
       Fall &2015 &Teaching Assistant, Machine Learning (Andrew Ng)\\
       Winter &2016 &Teaching Assistant, Cryptography (Dan Boneh)\\
       Winter &2017&\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{Teaching Assistant, 
       Probabilistic Graphical Model (Stefano Ermon)}\\
\end{tabular}
```

But this makes text of third line much larger compared to above two.

[image]

What's the best practice to control font size in this kind of situation so that all the lines have same font size at the same time fit on one line?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Try by starting `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{` before the environment. The right brace `}` has to be placed at the end, right after `\end{tabular}`

Comment: Please don't use `resizebox` for tables. This will just scale the font without choosing a font of appropriate size. If you insist on changing the font size of the table, do it manually, e.g. `\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont`.

Comment: the font is larger because `\textwidth` is larger than the width allowed for the column, but the string you are placing in it is not quite that wide.  you may end up with a line that is wider than the width of the text block.  better to adjust the width of the column, as suggested in the answers, or even  to set the column `\raggedright`, avoiding hyphenation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using another scaling of the font (which you get using `\resizebox`) or another fontsize for only a small portion of a document will look really strange. My suggestion instead is split the last cell in two lines and let latex determine the optimal columns widths:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}llX@{}}
     Fall &2015 &Teaching Assistant, Machine Learning (Andrew Ng)\\
     Winter &2016 &Teaching Assistant, Cryptography (Dan Boneh)\\
     Winter &2017&Teaching Assistant, 
     Probabilistic Graphical Model\newline (Stefano Ermon)\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you insist on a single line, you could save a btit of space beteween the columns and make the last one a bit wider (as I don't know which documentclass etc. you are using I cannot say if this will fit in your textwidth or not)

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llp{4.03in}@{}}
     Fall &2015 &Teaching Assistant, Machine Learning (Andrew Ng)\\
     Winter &2016 &Teaching Assistant, Cryptography (Dan Boneh)\\
     Winter &2017&Teaching Assistant, 
     Probabilistic Graphical Model (Stefano Ermon)\\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]